# Convert integer columns to double

Tags: r, type-conversion

I imported 2 csv files containing experiment data, one being the control group and one the test group. Heads shown here

[image]

The problem is that in 'Gaze_T' the columns 5+ are of type double, while in 'Gaze_C' they're of type integer.

So when doing a summary on the distance in both dataframes I get different outputs

[image]

How can I convert the integer columns in Gaze_C to double?

Comment: Your `summary(Gaze_C$Distance)` looks more like it is a factor than anything else. Try `Gaze_C$Distance <- as.numeric(as.factor(Gaze_C$Distance))`. Or use the `colClasses` parameter when you read the csv file using `read.table()`.

Comment: According to you `head(Gaze_C)` output, `Gaze_C$distance` is definitely not an integer column. It might be a factor, which means you should check your source file for non-numeric values in this column and handle that during import.

Comment: As Stephan suggested I converted the columns to numerics, which indeed was the problem.

Comment: @Rickyfox, I know this problem is solved, but for future problems if you are not already familiar with ```str```, that command (e.g. ```str(Gaze_C)```) will let you see the type of each variable when initially inspecting your data. If you are using ```library(dplyr)``` you can also use ```glimpse(Gaze_C)``` for similar inspection. Based on your post it seems like you may not be familiar with these commands yet? If not, hopefully these will be helpful to you in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use as.DATATYPE(column)

```
as.double(Gaze_T$Distance)
```

This converts the column Distance in Gaze_T to double.