# Coding for data.frame columns, integer and numeric. R studio

Tags: r, dataframe

Good day to all of you. I just would like to know if the following code in R will do what I would like it to do. Here it is:

```r
for(i in 1:ncol(badClassFrame)) {
  if (is.integer(badClassFrame)) {
    as.numeric(badClassFrame)
  }
}
```

I think it is correct and I believe it goes through each column of a data.frame called "badClassFrame", in which each column contains an integer-classed data, and converts them into numeric data. I just would like to confirm my theory. Thank you for reading my message. Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm confused about your question -- are you not able to run the code, or are you asking how would one test if it had worked?

Comment: We can run `df <- data.frame(a = 1L); for(i in 1:ncol(df)){if(is.integer(df)){as.numeric(df)}}; str(df)` to see that it has not worked and the integer column in df is still integer.

Comment: Here is a related question about how to convert from integer to double in R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379647/convert-integer-columns-to-double

Comment: (1) You appear to be iterating over columns with `i` but never use `i`, so your `is.integer(.)` is always going to be `FALSE`. (2) R generally does not work in [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), so while `as.numeric(some_integer_vector)` will convert it to `numeric`, it doesn't do anything with it, so the original vector remains `integer`. You need to assign it back on itself. I suggest something like `if (is.integer(badClassFrame[[i]])) badClassFrame[[i]] <- as.numeric(badClassFrame[[i]])` as a literal translation of your code.

Comment: Though likely better: `isint <- sapply(badClassFrame, is.integer); badClassFrame[isint] <- lapply(badClassFrame[isint], as.numeric)` will do it more concisely.

Comment: @r2evans. Thank you for answering my question and giving me all your explanations. And thank you for the suggestions as well. Have a nice day

Comment: @JonSpring. Thank you for the link and for answering my question. Have a nice day.